# VisualG - Exercício com procedimento

Tags: portugol, visualg

Boa tarde galera, tudo certo?

Estou com um exercício de Algoritmos I, e tô preso numa dúvida. A questão:

***- Escreva um procedimento que receba um número inteiro e o imprima na forma extensa. Por exemplo, para 1 a saída desejada é “Um”. A função deve ser capaz de gerar o extenso dos números de 1 até 15, inclusive. Caso um número não compatível seja recebido o procedimento deve mostrar uma mensagem de erro. Crie também um algoritmo que leia um valor inteiro e chame o procedimento criado acima para a impressão do número extenso.***

Meu código:

```
algoritmo "APS09"
var
   num: inteiro

procedimento FormaExtensa(n:inteiro)
var
   extenso:caracter
inicio
      escolha n
              caso "1"
                   extenso <- "Um"
              caso "2"
                   extenso <- "Dois"
              caso "3"
                   extenso <- "Três"
              caso "4"
                   extenso <- "Quatro"
              caso "5"
                   extenso <- "Cinco"
              caso "6"
                   extenso <- "Seis"
              caso "7"
                   extenso <- "Sete"
              caso "8"
                   extenso <- "Oito"
              caso "9"
                   extenso <- "Nove"
              caso "10"
                   extenso <- "Dez"
              caso "11"
                   extenso <- "Onze"
              caso "12"
                   extenso <- "Doze"
              caso "13"
                   extenso <- "Treze"
              caso "14"
                   extenso <- "Quatorze"
              caso "15"
                   extenso <- "Quinze"
              outrocaso
                   extenso <- "Número não compatível"
      fimescolha
      escreval(extenso)
fimprocedimento

inicio

      escreva("Digite um número até 15: ")
      leia(num)

      FormaExtensa(num)

fimalgoritmo
```

Porém, na hora de rodar, ele pede para digitar o número certinho, porém, qualquer número que eu digite, ele da um erro no `caso "1"` e diz que esperava um INTEIRO. Ainda não entendi aonde ele esperava um valor inteiro.

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa?
Agradeço desde já.

**[RESOLUÇÃO]**

Apenas removi as aspas do caso, como sugerido em resposta ao post.

```
caso 1
                   extenso <- "Um"
              caso 2
                   extenso <- "Dois"
              caso 3
                   extenso <- "Três"
              caso 4
                   extenso <- "Quatro"
              caso 5
                   extenso <- "Cinco"
              caso 6
                   extenso <- "Seis"
              caso 7
                   extenso <- "Sete"
              caso 8
                   extenso <- "Oito"
              caso 9
                   extenso <- "Nove"
              caso 10
                   extenso <- "Dez"
              caso 11
                   extenso <- "Onze"
              caso 12
                   extenso <- "Doze"
              caso 13
                   extenso <- "Treze"
              caso 14
                   extenso <- "Quatorze"
              caso 15
                   extenso <- "Quinze"
              outrocaso
                   extenso <- "Número não compatível"
      fimescolha
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vê se não é porque você colocou entres aspas duplas "", ele espera receber um número porém esta sendo comparado com uma string, no caso seria tipo assim:

```
escolha n:
    case 1 extenso <- "UM"
    case 2 extenso <- "DOIS"
    ...
fimescolha
```

Comment: Exatamente isso meu amigo... Que mole que eu marquei. hahaha
Agradeço da mesmo forma. Já até editei o post com a resolução